# Drupal 7 jQuery issue

Tags: jquery, drupal-7

I know Drupal 7 jQuery code needs to be wrapped in a way which allows other libraries that use the **$** notation to work. I have accounted for that as my code below shows:

```
(function($){
    alert('working');
    console.log('working');
    jQuery('#logo').hide();
    $('table#nodesequence_nodes').click(
        function(){
            console.log('still working');
        }
    );
})(jQuery);
```

The strange thing is, my calls to **$** and **jQuery** don't work. The code to hide **#logo** for instance does not work neighter does the table click code. They don't generate errors  ... they are simply completely unresponsive.

The alert and console.log code samples DO work.

My jQuery and my JavaScript file are both successfully loaded according to firebug.

Comment: Are you sure your javascript is even included with the html page?

Comment: very sure. Otherwise my alert and console.log statements won't work ... which they do!

Comment: I think it might be because not all the HTML has loaded yet.  You should try using the Drupal prescribed way of running scripts.  Go to this page and scroll down to the section titled "Behaviors": http://drupal.org/node/756722

Comment: Thank you Kevin628, you were right. I don't entirely understand it but it solved my problem. Provide it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be because not all the HTML has loaded yet. You should try using the Drupal prescribed way of running scripts. Go to this page and scroll down to the section titled "Behaviors": [drupal.org/node/756722](http://drupal.org/node/756722)